# Sort a list of dictionaries by a specific key within a nested list of dictionaries

Tags: sorting, dictionary, data-structures, nested-lists

I have a list of dictionaries with each entry having the following structure

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "type": "notification",
  "name": "jane doe",
  "loc": {
    "lat": 38.8239,
    "long": 104.7001
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "test",
      "time": "Fri Aug 13 09:17:16 2021",
      "df": 80000000,
      "db": 1000000,
      "tp": 92
    },
    {
      "type": "real",
      "time": "Sat Aug 14 09:21:30 2021",
      "df": 70000000,
      "db": 2000000,
      "tp:": 97
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to sort this list by any of these keys: `name, type, time, tp` and return it in memory.

I understand how to sort by the top level keys `sorted(json_list, key=lambda k:k['name'])` or even nested keys. For instance by lat `sorted(json_list, key=lambda k:k['loc']['lat'])`

so currently I have a function that works for the case when sorting by `name`.

```
  def sort_by(self, param, rev=False):
    if param == NAME:
      self.json_list = sorted(self.json_list, key=lambda k: k[param], reverse=rev)
    else:
      #  need help here
```

I'm having trouble sorting by `type, time, and tp`. Notice the `data` key is also a list of dictionaries. I would like to leverage existing methods built into the standard lib if possible. I can provide more clarification if necessary

**Update:**

```
  def sort_by(self, param, rev=False):
    if param == NAME:
      self.json_list = sorted(self.json_list, key=lambda k: k[param], reverse=rev)
    else:
      self.json_list = sorted(self.json_list, key=lambda k: k['data'][0][param], reverse=rev)

    return self.json_list
```

This works fine if there is only one item in the `data` list

Comment: It would help if you provided samples where the list in `data` has more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

If `json_list[i]['data']` (for each `i`) only contains one `dict`, then the following should work; otherwise modifications are required.

```
sorted(json_list, key = lambda k: (
    k['name'], k['data']['type'], k['data']['time'], k['data']['tp']
))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because data is a list. Pretty sure this will throw a TypeError.

Comment: Also i see you thought i meant i need to sort by all those keys at once. I actually only need to sort by one key at a time. Not a combination. Thanks for asking that so I could refine my question!

Comment: In your updates I see you could at least use a brute-force if-elif-else to handle different keys, depending on the parameter. So what if the data list has more than one element?